# How do I use fs.readFile() in this context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fs

I am building a website in NodeJS.

I have a function that looks like this:

```js
function buildHTML(place) {
  var template = fs.readFileSync('templates/home.html');
  switch (place) {
    case 'home':
      console.log('Generating home.html');
      var page = fs.readFileSync('templates/home.html');
      var generated = template.replace('<dump></dump>', page);
      var replaceWith = '<p class="content">This was generated from scratch on <em>' + Date() + '</em></p>';
      return generated.replace('<dump></dump>', replaceWith);
      break
    case 'browse':
      console.log('Generating browse.html');
      var page = fs.readFileSync('templates/browse.html');
      var generated = template.replace('<dump></dump>', page);
      var replaceWith = '<p class="content">This was generated from scratch on <em>' + Date() + '</em></p>';
      return generated.replace('<dump></dump>', replaceWith);
      break
  }
};
```

The idea is that I have one "template" file, with a NavBar, footer, and all the stuff I want looking exactly the same across pages.
Then I have multiple "insert" files, with some HTML that is unique to every page.
After that (I haven't built this part yet), I have more code that is generated server-side before getting sent to the user. This will be used for automatic catalogs and similar.

I know perfectly how to use `fs.readFileSync()`, however if I use this, the code will continue executing without waiting for it to finish. Then I get an error, and even if I catch the error, it will still act not how I want it to, because then it hasn't loaded the pages.

I've tried experimenting with `fs.readFile(file, function(err, data){})`, but after an hour, I still could not manage it. I get error after error, and I have no idea how I would fit the rest of the functions inside those curly brackets so it will only execute when done loading the file.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you reinventing templating?

Comment: I was unaware there were already solutions to this. Unless there are some serious benefits, I will likely not be changing how this is done.

Comment: There are at least a half-dozen solutions. Rolling your own is... tedious and error-prone. There are searious benefits to using known, tested, feature-rich, pre-existing solutions to long-solved problems. Hopefully you're not also rolling your own web framework too.

Comment: It's just this. I don't need a whole template engine if all I need is this. I would much rather have full control over everything than to use something I have to install and learn.

Comment: You over-estimate the difficulty of using existing solutions, but ok. Good luck!

Comment: Look at `page` variable immediatly after `readFileSync`. What you see?

Comment: Yeah, I see that, it's supposed to be `default`.